# ActiveX doesn't show up in Browser

Tags: asp-classic, activex

i'm trying to put an activeX object on an asp-webpage.
it already worked good a week ago, but now the object isn't showing up anymore.
already made a little asp testing-project....just an asp-page and a activex control, containing a button and a label.
but when i call up the page in the browser, there is only a white area with a little icon in the upper left corner, showing a red dot, a green triangle and a blue rectangle....
what does that mean?

object not found?
object blocked by IE?
or what exactly does this icon stand for?
i always thoght that an missing object is represented by an empty area with a little red cross in it. =/

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that the path to the codebase was correct?